# How to dynamically insert images into Bootstrap Popover

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I want to use popover to show product images. Any idea how I can grab the image from the `data-img` attribute correctly? Thank you.

```html
<a href='#' class='toggle-popover' title='Hello World' data-img='http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo11w.png' data-trigger='focus' data-toggle='popover'>Product Name</a>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    title: '',
    trigger: 'hover',
    content: '<div class="row">' +
      '<div class="col-sm-12 text-center ">' +
      '<div class="content3">' +
      '<div class="pt-3"><img src="' + $(this).data('img') + '"/></div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>',
    html: true
  });
});
```

`$(this).data('img')` shows as `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.each()` to iterate and set the popover `content` using current context i.e. `this`

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function(){
    $(this).popover({
    title: '',
    trigger: 'hover',
    content: '<div class="row">' +
      '<div class="col-sm-12 text-center ">' +
      '<div class="content3">' +
      '<div class="pt-3"><img src="' + $(this).data('img') + '"/></div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
      '</div>',
    html: true
  })
});
```